# How to connect to socket (c)?

Tags: c, sockets, server

I cannot connect to my server program via sockets.

My server program works fine with telnet connections.

I cant spot the problem, any ideas?

```
int main(void){
int sockfd =0;
char recvBuff[1024];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
    return 1;
} 

memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

if(inet_pton(AF_INET,"192.168.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
{
    printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
    return 1;
} 

if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr.sin_addr, sizeof(serv_addr.sin_addr)) < 0)
{
   printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
   return 1;
} 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: first of all you should print the errno in all error cases.

Comment: [sigh] what happens, what gets printed out, what is perror/errno?

Comment: .. for example instead of `printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");` use `perror("connect() failed");`

Comment: .. and do that for all system calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
   printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
   return 1;
}
```

[Here is a good tutorial](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Please also take into account the important advise given in *[J Carl Zeigler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6304107/j-carl-zeigler)*'s [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37572243/694576)!]

You want to delete this line

```
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
```

as it just overwrites what you initialised `serv_addr` to before by doing this:

```
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons( 8888 );
```

---

Just guessing that you probably wanted to zero-out the target address member you are trying to set here:

```
if(inet_pton(AF_INET,"192.168.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
```

This would then have looked like this:

```
memset(&serv_addr.sin_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr.sin_addr));
```

(note the usage of the value `0` instead of the character `'0'`, which most likely evaluates to the value `48` if using ASCII on your system)

Any ways zeroing it out before is not needed, as `inet_pton()` takes care of fully properly setting the `sin_addr` member.

---

And the next thing you might like to do is learn how to use a debugger to fix such stxxid issues yourself.

Comment: LOL - OP must have slipped up when copy/pasting from wherever.. ;)